# how to ForEach loop in Menu View SwiftUI

Tags: swift, loops, swiftui, foreach

Hello everyone and happy new Year. I figure out an issue in .toolbar Menu. I show u :

```
.toolbar {                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading){
                    Menu{
                        Button("All"){
                            self.paintsModel = dataManager.sortPaintsModelByYear()
                        }
                        //MARK: Categories
                        ForEach(dataManager.fetchCategory()){ category in
                            Button(category.name){
                                self.paintsModel = dataManager.getPaintsModelByCategory(categoryModel: category)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                    } label: {
                        Label("",systemImage: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle")
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

The error message says :

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug repor

and I did not know why ...

For info `dataManager.fetchCategory()` returns an array of type `[PaintModel]` which is an Identifiable

Thanks in advance for any response or solution.

I think the issue is due to .toolbar but I don't know why

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your question.